# Add a new property within the original tree structure while iterating recursively

Tags: javascript

Below is the tree structure

```
 data= [
            {
              "name": "Company",
              "url": "",
              "submenu": [
                {
                  "name": "Company Wiki",
                  "url": "",
                  "submenu": [
                    {
                        "name": "Company Wiki2",
                        "url": "",
                        "submenu": [{
                            "name": "Company Wiki3",
                            "url": "http://my.company.co/wiki",
                            "submenu":null
                        }]                      
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "Company Jira",
                  "url": "https://facebook.com",
                  "submenu": null
                },
                {
                  "name": "Google",
                  "url": "http://www.google.com",
                  "submenu": null
                },
                {
                  "name": "Yahoo",
                  "url": "http://www.yahoo.com",
                  "submenu": null
                }, {
                    "name": "Company ",
                    "url": "http://www.Company.io",
                    "submenu": null
                }, {
                    "name": "Test Submenu6",
                    "url": "http://www.Company.io",
                    "submenu": null
                }, {
                    "name": "Test Submenu7",
                    "url": "http://www.Company.io",
                    "submenu": null
                }, {
                    "name": "Test Submenu8",
                    "url": "http://www.Company.io",
                    "submenu": null
                }
              ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Department",
                "submenu": [{
                    "name": "Department Wiki",
                    "url": "http://my.company.co/wiki",
                    "submenu": null
                }, {
                    "name": "Test Wiki",
                    "url": "http://my.company.co/wiki",
                    "submenu": null
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Documents",
                "url": "http://my.company.co/wiki",
                "submenu": null
            }
          ];
```

I have a set of values

```
   ["Company", "Company Wiki", "Company Wiki2",  "Company Wiki3"]
```

I need to modify the above tree structure such that nodes with the above names should contain a property called visible true.

```
  function transverse (root, newArr, visibleSet) {
debugger;
if(visibleSet.has(root.name)) {
    root =  {...root, visible:true}
}else {
    root = {...root, visible:false}
}
 newArr.push(root);

 if (root.sub === null || root.sub.length === 0) {  

     return root;
 }

 if (root.hasOwnProperty("sub") && root.sub instanceof Array)
    root.sub.map(child => {
        transverse(child, newArr, visibleSet);
    });

}

 var str = "";
 data.forEach(item => {
     newData.push(transverse(item,[], visibleSet));
});
```

The above code adds the `visible:true` property based on name but the structure of the tree is not maintained when adding the node back to the array. How to maintain the structure of the tree within the recursive loop while adding a new property to it? Or to create a duplicate tree with the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could a recursive approach by looking for the given values and update with a function.

```js
function update(array, fn, [key, ...keys]) {
    return array.some(o => {
        if (o.name === key) {
            if (!keys.length) {
                fn(o);
                return true;
            }
            return update(o.submenu, fn, keys);
        }
    });
}


var data = [{ name: "Company", url: "", submenu: [{ name: "Company Wiki", url: "", submenu: [{ name: "Company Wiki2", url: "", submenu: [{ name: "Company Wiki3", url: "http://my.company.co/wiki", icon: "folder_shared", submenu: null }] }] }, { name: "Company Jira", url: "https://facebook.com", submenu: null }, { name: "Google", url: "http://www.google.com", submenu: null }, { name: "Yahoo", url: "http://www.yahoo.com", submenu: null }, { name: "Company ", url: "http://www.Company.io", submenu: null }, { name: "Test Submenu6", url: "http://www.Company.io", submenu: null }, { name: "Test Submenu7", url: "http://www.Company.io", submenu: null }, { name: "Test Submenu8", url: "http://www.Company.io", submenu: null }] }, { name: "Department", submenu: [{ name: "Department Wiki", url: "http://my.company.co/wiki", submenu: null }, { name: "Test Wiki", url: "http://my.company.co/wiki", submenu: null }] }, { name: "Documents", url: "http://my.company.co/wiki", submenu: null }],
    keys = ["Company", "Company Wiki", "Company Wiki2", "Company Wiki3"];
  

update(data, o => o.visible = true, keys);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```